# How to select all values from a column except a value in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have the query:

```
$legend= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE rank = 'Legend' AND status='Alive' AND userlevel <> '2'"));
```

I need to know how you do the excluding sign, because it seams that `<>` is not correct.

Comment: what is <>? use `!=` instead! <> reminds me a part of a fish. ><>

Comment: You're doing it the right way, this should work, check your table if you have records with userlevel = 2, i mean execute the query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE userlevel = 2" i think that you will find 0 results.

Comment: Ah yes, it seams that this works too, `<>` and `!=`. Thank you all.

Comment: i bet you found 0 results in users table, am i right :-)

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash Found exactly what i needed, 1 result.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$legend= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE rank = 'Legend' AND status='Alive' AND userlevel != '2'"));
```

This should do the trick if i understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  users 
WHERE rank = 'Legend' 
AND status='Alive' 
AND userlevel != '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$legend= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE rank = 'Legend' AND status='Alive' AND userlevel !='2'"));
```

This will query results having `rank` as `Legend` and `status` as `Alive` excluding `userlevel` with `2`